# Create a SingleChoiceItems dialog in android with key->value

Tags: android, android-dialog

I have a string-array in my android resources:

```
<string-array name="retry_delay_entry_values2" translatable="false">
    <item name="blabla 1">5</item>
    <item name="blabla 2">10</item>
    <item name="blabla 3">30</item>
</string-array>
```

And I want to create an alertdialog based on this model: https://i.stack.imgur.com/l0ec3.png

I created

```
public Dialog onCreateDialog() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("blablabla")
            .setSingleChoiceItems(R.array.retry_delay_entry_values2, -1,
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "the value: "+which, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    })
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                }
            });

    return builder.create();
}
```

And I want that when I click "blabla 1" in the window, it displays the toast: "the value: 5". But in reality it displays "the value: 0" because this is the first item in the list.

How can I fix that please ?

Answer (score 0):

I tried your which you posted in question and it is working fine from my side.. Can you please try with clean project and run again.

```
  Dialog dialog = onCreateDialog();
  dialog.show();
```

Method

```
public Dialog onCreateDialog() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("blablabla")
                .setSingleChoiceItems(R.array.retry_delay_entry_values2, -1,
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "the value: " + which, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        });


        return builder.create();
    }
```

Array

```
<string-array name="retry_delay_entry_values2" translatable="false">
        <item name="blabla 1">5</item>
        <item name="blabla 2">10</item>
        <item name="blabla 3">30</item>
    </string-array>
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable `which` only gives you the index not the value.

To get the value you have to use this

```
getResources().getStringArray(R.array.retry_delay_entry_values2)[which]
```

like this

```
.setSingleChoiceItems(R.array.retry_delay_entry_values2, -1,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "the value: "+ 
                            getResources().getStringArray(R.array.retry_delay_entry_values2)[which],
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                })
```